# Pass in HTML input values to javascript function, then output JS outcome to <p> HTML

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

I'm doing some independent JavaScript learning and I'm trying to figure out how to pass parameters from HTML into the JavaScript and then output HTML from the JavaScript after the logic as finished.

In this example, I have two input text boxes and a button. Idealy, the text boxes will have numbers in them and the button will call the JavaScript. The JavaScript simply compares which number is greater than the other and then outputs the outcome to a `<p>` element with the id of "output". Code is as follows...

```
   <html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var htmlop = "";
            function compareX(a,b){
                if(a < b){
                    htmlop= a+"is greater than "+b;
                }
                else{
                    htmlop= b+"is greater than "+a;
                }
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = htmlop;
            }
        </script>
        <div>
            Input1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></br>
            Input2: <input type="text" name="input2" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Run Logic" onclick="compareX(document.getElementByName("input1").value,document.getElementByName("input2").value)" />
        </div></br></br>
        <div>
            <p id="output"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not getting any type of output here and I do not know of anyway to tell if the values from the HTML are being passed into the JavaScript correctly. Can anyone provide help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposted Code if you want to use name instead of id please use above code with revising function call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var htmlop = "";

    function compareX(a,b){

        if(parseInt(a) < parseInt(b)){
            htmlop= a+"is greater than "+b;
        }
        else{
            htmlop= b+"is greater than "+a;
        }
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = htmlop;
    }
</script>
<div>
    Input1: <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1"></br>
    Input2: <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Run Logic" onclick='compareX(document.getElementById("input1").value,document.getElementById("input2").value )' />
</div></br></br>
<div>
    <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var htmlop = "";
            function compareX(){
                var a=document.getElementsByName('input1')[0].value;
                var b=document.getElementsByName("input2")[0].value;

                if(a < b){
                    htmlop= a+" is greater than "+b;
                }
                else{
                    htmlop= b+" is greater than "+a;
                }

                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = htmlop;
            }
        </script>
        <div>
            Input1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></br>
            Input2: <input type="text" name="input2" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Run Logic" onclick="compareX()" />
        </div></br></br>
        <div>
            <p id="output"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this here you have another issue, in your code you are comparing a with b and supposing they are integer but in reality they are strings so you will not be able to get your desired results. try to change to your javascript code as well.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var htmlop = "";
        function compareX(a,b){
            if(parseInt(a) < parseInt(b)){
                htmlop= a+"is greater than "+b;
            }
            else{
                htmlop= b+"is greater than "+a;
            }
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = htmlop;
        }
    </script>
    <div>
        Input1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></br>
        Input2: <input type="text" name="input2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Run Logic" onclick="compareX(document.getElementsByName("input1")[0].value, document.getElementsByName("input2")[0].value)" />
    </div></br></br>
    <div>
        <p id="output"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I made your suggested changes

'if(parseInt(a) < parseInt(b))' and 'compareX(document.getElementByName('input1')[0].value,document.getElementByName('input2')[0].value)'

I'm still not getting the '<p>' innerHTML to change!

Comment: i am re-posting my answer now it's working fine actually you were calling function was using wrong quote's

Comment: Could it not be working for me because I'm testing it in Notepad++?

Comment: no it's not an issue with notepad++ this line was causing this issue <input type="button" value="Run Logic" onclick="compareX(document.getElementsByName("input1")[0].value, document.getElementsByName("input2")[0].value)" />

Comment: if you replace outer double quotes with single quote it will work.